# What geodetic reference system is QGIS using when providing latitude and longitude values for points using the field calculator?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

When working in a projected map (project properties have a projection chosen), QGIS calculates longitude (`$x`) and latitude (`$y`) values for each point (or polygon centroid) as decimal degrees. (This is when using the field calculator to obtain lat/long). What geodetic reference system is QGIS using to provide lat/long values when using the field calculator?

I have made a few trials with a shapefile in `WGS 84` and `NAD 83` and the decimal.degrees values are the same in both shapefiles. However, they shouldn't be have the same values past the 5th or 6th decimal (based on using an online conversion tool from `WSG 84` to `NAD 83`: https://tagis.dep.wv.gov/convert/)

EDIT: clarify the steps I made to test decimal.degrees values in a project using a projected CRS (NAD 83 MTM8)

1. Create new point shapefile
2. Create random cluster of points
3. Save point shapefile with `WGS 84` as CRS (`points_WGS84.shp`)
4. Save point shapefile with `NAD 83` as CRS (`points_NAD83.shp`)
5. Load `points_WGS84.shp` in QGIS
6. Open attribute table, open field calculator, create new field (`long`) with 8 decimal points, enter `$x` in the calculator box [`points_WGS84.shp` file]
7. Open attribute table, open field calculator, create new field (`lat`) with 8 decimal points, enter `$y` in the calculator box [`points_WGS84.shp` file]
8. Load `points_NAD83.shp` in QGIS
9. Open attribute table, open field calculator, create new field (`long`) with 8 decimal points, enter `$x` in the calculator box [`points_NAD83.shp` file]
10. Open attribute table, open field calculator, create new field (`lat`) with 8 decimal points, enter `$y` in the calculator box [`points_NAD83.shp` file]
11. Open attribute tables for `points_WGS84.shp` and for `points_NAD83.shp`
12. Compare values between both tables --> conclusion: they are identical to the last decimal

Comment: If you use the field calculator to populate a field with lat/long values, that field will not automatically update when the lat/long changes. Use a Virtual Field if you want an auto-updating field.

Comment: I am not interested in automatically updating the lat/long values. I want to know what geodetic reference system QGIS is using initially.

Comment: My point was just that you need to manually re-calculate the lat/long value when you change the CRS. If you did that already, then it's not relevant. If you didn't, your underlying assumption (that QGIS gives the same decimal degree value in WGS84 and NAD83) might be incorrect.

Comment: I created one file with the projection WGS84 and one file in NAD83. THEN I used field calculator to obtain lat and long, which were in decimal.degrees.

Comment: The NAD83 definition in QGIS probably doesn't have a +TOWGS84 parameter in its definition, so no conversion has been / will be done.

Comment: conversion from what to what?

Comment: I think there is a bug... When I use the `x($geometry(transform...` and specify `EPSG:4269` (NAD83) vs `EPSG:4326` (WSG84), I get the same lat/long values.

Comment: Are you sure that saving a shapefile with a particular crs is the same thing as reprojecting it to that crs? Did you try using the 'reproject layer' tool explicitly?

Comment: I have used "save as..." in another crs successfully to switch between WSG84 to MTM8 to Lambert Conical. Every time, it does seem to function in the new projection correctly. Just to be sure, I tried this time with `reproject layer` using the tool and same results regarding lat/long in WSG84 vs. NAD83.